# My shiny app will not display any plots/words but will still run

Tags: shiny

My shiny app will not display anything except the dropdown menus (none of the text, images, plots, are showing). The app will run, however It will not display anything. I have gone through and checked for any misspelled words, errors with commons and that sort of thing, but they all seem to be correct. There are no R errors popping up in the console. It purely just decided to stop working. I am trying to understand how, but I have reached a roadblock.

This is my Ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(d3heatmap)

conf_stats <- read.csv("conference_stats.csv")
conf_avg <- read.csv("conference_statsAVG.csv")
heatmap_stats <- read.csv("heatmap_data.csv")

dashboardPage(
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardHeader(title = "NCAA Basketball"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "page1"),
      menuItem("Conference Statistics", tabName = "page2"),
      menuItem("Maps", tabName = "page3")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "page1", p("Home"),
              h2("Welcome!"),
              imageOutput("home_img"),
              box(background = "blue", p("Welcome to Our Shiny App!")),
              imageOutput("logo_img"),
              box(
                width = 5,
                status = "info",
                textOutput("textBox"))
      ),
      
      tabItem(tabName = "page2", p("Conference Statistics"),
              selectInput(
                "y_var",
                label = "Conference Data",
                choices = colnames(conf_stats),
                selected = "Conference"),
                plotOutput("plot"),
              box(
                width = 5,
                status = "info",
                textOutput("confExp")),
                
      tabItem(tabName = "page3", 
              tabPanel("Conference Statistics",
  # Bar Graph for Conference           
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  title = "Conference Data",
                  status = "primary",
                  width = 6,
                  selectInput(
                    "y_var",
                    label = "Conference Data",
                    choices = colnames(conf_avg),
                    selected = "Conference")
                ),
                plotOutput("plot")
              ),
  
  # Heat Map for Conference
              fluidRow(
            box(
              title = "Choose Conference",
              status = "primary",
              width = 6,
              selectInput( "YEAR", "Select Year", unique(heatmap_stats$YEAR),
                           selected = max(heatmap_stats$YEAR, multiple =FALSE)),
  # This is the actual heatmap
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  d3heatmapOutput("heatmapPlot")
                )
              )
    )
    
    )
  )
    )
  )
      )
    )
)
```

This is my server.

```
# loading the necessary libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(d3heatmap)

# specifying our conference data used in conference tab
conf_stats <- read.csv("conference_stats.csv")
conf_avg <- read.csv("conference_statsAVG.csv")
heatmap_stats <- read.csv("heatmap_data.csv")


function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$home_img <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = "www/header_img.png",
         width = "800",
         height = 200)
    
  }, deleteFile = F)
  
  output$logo_img <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = "www/logo_img.png",
         width = "450",
         height = 400)
    
  }, deleteFile = F)
  
  
  output$textBox <- renderText({
    "Welcome to our cutting-edge dashboard, where we look at a decades worth of statistical data on NCAA Division 1 basketball teams. The postseason
    period of college basketball, coined March Madness, is one of the most revered sporting events of all time. Statistical data covers both in-season and post-season information, including importatn points such as power ranking, win percentage,
    period of college basketball, coined 'March Madness'', is one of the most revered sporting events of all time. Statistical data covers both in-season and post-season information, including importatn points such as power ranking, win percentage,
    and free throw success. This data illustrates a unique narrative about each season and how the game of basektball has evolved over the 
    last decade. Data can be used to understand conference performance, recruitment patterns, the impact of rule changes and adaptations, 
    and team trends over time. This app provides a comprehensive understanding of the sport's development over time by identifying patterns and
    trends useful for anyone who appreciates the sport. Important to note, however, is the COVID-19 pandemic that occurred; there is not data from the year 2020,
    because postseason college basketbakll games were not held."
  })
  


  # Conference tab bar graph
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
          req(input$y_var)
        ggplot(data=conf_avg, aes_string(x='Conference',
                                       y=input$y_var)) +
              geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
              labs(x="Conference", y=input$y_var)
  })
        
  # Conference Tab Heat Map
    output$heatmapPlot <- renderD3heatmap({
          req(input$YEAR)
      df <- heatmap_stats %>%
        filter(YEAR == input$YEAR)
      row.names(df) <- df$Conference
      df$Conference <- NULL
       d3heatmap(as.matrix(df))
         })
          
}
```

I am a novice at shiny and do not know how to fix this. Please help!

Comment: It is difficult to run your app without the csv files.